# Meaning of the chinese translation of italian name Federico

Tags: translation, meaning

This is my first question here so I don't even kwow if it's permitted to ask this kind of questions.

The fact is that I would like to know the meaning of my name: 费代里科 (fèi dài lǐ kē),  which is the phonetic translation of Federico, if I understood well.

Comment: One may wonder whether most Chinese are aware of the common origin of Federico, Friedrich/弗里德里希 (as in Friedrich Engels) Fritz/弗利茨, Fred/福来德.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be more "费德瑞克" than 费代里科, as Rico is normally translated into "瑞克", and "de" sounds more similar to "德".

However, I wish that you could understand that normally in Chinese, an individual word can have multiple meanings, and sometimes those meanings are not related.
For the 4 words you have presented:
费代里科

费 : If it is used as a noun, it can be a common chinese family name Or fees & fares Or costs; If it is used as a verb, it usually means cost.

代 : This word is usually considered as a verb, means represent/do someone else’s work in his or her place/replace; it can also be a rare Chinese family name, and the noun of represent.

里 : It’s similar to « Inside ».

科 : This is a noun. It can mean subject, family of animals & plants(biologics),  a unit of collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically it's the phonetic translation. And no strange word is used.

Comment: This I don't know. Even there is no particular meaning, at least Chinese word looks beautiful. Good luck!